# Generating Own Session Id in JSF

Tags: java, session, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have a web application in which we use JSF framework.
I have been diving deep into the security part for web application and hence I was looking to generate my own unique session ID(using encryption algorithm and assign it to every new session which gets created once user logs in.

Can anyone please guide me on how to set manual generated session id in session and ensure with each request that session id is transmitted.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not using the one generated by the container for you?

Comment: @JB Nizet Purely because of security reasons and my applications demands that the session ID should be generated manually using a strong encryption algorithm.Kindly guide me on how to set the session id.

Comment: @McDowell Thanks for the reply.However implementing SPI will have there own pro's and con's and morever there will be an extra buden to properly secure SPI and look into how to integrate features of container specific SPI with the container...I am looking more at a robust solution rather than trying to implement a container SPI..Any solution from java or j2ee point of view will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really doubt you'll generate session IDs that are more secure than the ones generated by the container, but here's what you could do, without using any container-specific extension.

Create a servlet filter which intercept every request to the server.

When a request comes in, check if a session already exists for this request (using `getSession(false)`). If one exists, then extract your specific cookie MY_SESSION_ID from the request, and compare its value to the one that is stored in the session. If they don't match, reject the request.

If the session doesn't exist, then create it (using `getSession(true)`), generate your super-secure session ID, store it as a session attribute and add the cookie MY_SESSION_ID to the response.

This has the disadvantage of creating a session automatically, even if it's not strictly needed. But that's the case most of the time when using JSPs of component frameworks.

Comment: I already have a filter implemented which intercept all my request.Also creating a new session or accessing an existing session is also done. However storing the super secure session id in session attribute and adding cookie MY_SESSION_ID to the response will solve my query absolutely...

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to do this at the JSF application layer is unlikely to be successful; I would perform this task at a lower level API. I am assuming a servlet container.

I can think of two approaches:

1. do this at a container level via a server-specific SPI (if one even exists)
2. do this by rewriting requests/responses via a servlet [Filter](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

There is insufficient information to comment on the viability of the first approach.

In the second, you would have to determine the name of the session cookie (it is usually JSESSIONID, but does not have to be). Your API would:

1. map the filter to all application requests
2. maintain a map of container session ids to "secure" ids
3. use the filter to rewrite any session cookie in the request with the session id
4. use the filter rewrite any session cookie in the response with the secure id
5. use a [listener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to remove invalid sessions from the map to avoid memory leaks