# Can I manually set session ID in Java?

Tags: java, session, servlets, session-timeout, httpsession

I am developing a simple publish subscribe application in Java. I am planning to use session ID as channels/topics. Can I set the session ID manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [httpservletrequest - create new session / change session Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311429/httpservletrequest-create-new-session-change-session-id)

Comment: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1499581/1031945) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7817431/1031945)